# bash: history favourites file

Tags: bash

i have a `.bash_favourites` file which containes a list of my favourite commands.
I  would like this be searchable via the normal bash history.   ???

thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

```
cat ~/.bash_favourites >> ~/.bash_history
history -r
```

If you want to make this permanent, you can probably just add these lines to ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the regular history with your favorites:
Do `chmod u-w` on `.bash_history` and edit it as you like. Bash should read it as usual but not add new commands.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which allows bookmarking of your favorite commands (on top of Bash history) and searching - check my favorites filtered with `e`:

[image]

Alternatively you can use trailing comments in commands you are entering i.e. `#` to bookmark them and search e.g.

`$ find -name kernel -type d # favorite`

and then search for `favorite` using <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> in Bash.

Comment: HSTR stores favorites to `~/.hh_favorites` - thus you can easily reuse your `~/.bash_favorites`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a similar setup though I approached it differently exert from my project could be edited to force loading of your favorites first or optionally dynamically loaded with the bastory function

```
if [ "$today" = "$yesterday" ]; then
    cat ~/.bash_favourites > ~/.bash_history
    head --lines=-1  $bashHistory >> $HISTFILE
else
    touch $HOME/.bash/archive/$(date +%F --date="6 hours ago" ).bash_history
    cat ~/.bash_favourites > ~/.bash_history
    cat $HOME/.bash/archive/$(date +%F  --date="6 hours ago" ).bash_history >> $HISTFILE
    head --lines=-1  $bashHistory >> $HISTFILE
fi
```

AS this is a old thread I will expand on this and incorporate it into my bashory project please refer comments on my answer to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32575/project-bashory-bash-history